# ASP.NET Core Configuration Section in Startup

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

I am migrating a ASP.NET 5 RC1 project to ASP.NET Core, and have come across an interesting issue I've not yet seen, or found a solution for.

In order to use configuration settings within Startup I have previously retrived the configuration the following way

```
// Works fine for DI both in ASP.NET 5 RC1 and ASP.NET Core
services.Configure<SomeConfigurationClass>(Configuration.GetSection("SomeConfigurationSection"));

// How I previous retrieved the configuration for use in startup. 
// No longer available in ASP.NET Core
var someConfigurationToUseLater = Configuration.Get<SomeConfigurationClass>("SomeConfigurationSection");
```

After updating to ASP.NET Core 1.0 it seems Configuration.Get<T>() is no longer available.

I have tried updating the code to use Configuration.GetValue<T>() however this does not seem to work with objects and will only work when providing a path to a value. This has left me with a workaround for *most* of my configuration classes like so

```
var someConfigurationName = "someConfiguration";    
var someConfigurationClass = new SomeConfigurationClass()
{
    Value1 = Configuration.GetValue<string>($"{someConfigurationName}:value1"),
    Foo = Configuration.GetValue<string>($"{someConfigurationName}:foo"),
    Bar = Configuration.GetValue<string>($"{someConfigurationName}:bar")
};
```

However this is an issue when the configuration class contains an array of objects. In my case an array of Client objects

```
public class ClientConfiguration
{
    public Client[] Clients { get; set; }
}
```

With the following configuration

```
"configuredClients": {
  "clients": [
    {
      "clientName": "Client1",
      "clientId": "Client1"
    },
    {
      "clientName": "Client2",
      "clientId": "Client2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Where this would previously bind to the Clients property of my configuration class no problem, I can no longer find a way of doing so in ASP.NET Core 1.0

Answer (score 87, accepted):

**Updated Answer**
For ASP Core 1.1.0 generic model binding is now done using `Get`:

```
var config = Configuration.GetSection("configuredClients").Get<ClientConfiguration>();
```

---

**Original Answer**
How about this:

```
var config = Configuration.GetSection("configuredClients").Bind<ClientConfiguration>();
```

Comment: It might be worth noting I had to update Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration and Microsoft.Extentions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions to 1.1.0-preview1-final

Comment: Has this been removed again in the final version of 1.1?

Comment: Looks like it might have been renamed to `Get<>`.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration#binding-to-an-object-graph

Comment: In order to work in 1.1 I had to add Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder from NuGet

Answer (score 11):

With **ASP.NET Core 2.0** (basically Core 1.1+), the `IConfiguration` is injected to `Startup`, and that can be used within `ConfigureServices()` and `Configure()` methods.

As shown in the accepted answer, the configuration can be bound to an object. But if just one value is required, the key based approach works well.

The `IConfiguration` still works with colon `:` separated string keys. And for `array`, use 0-based index. Or use the the generic `getValue<T>()` method with same keys. See example below:

```
var clientId2 = Configuration["configuredClients:clients:1:clientId"]?.ToString();
var clientName1 = Configuration.GetValue<string>("configuredClients:clients:0:clientName");
```

---

To use the same configuration values in other classes (e.g. Controllers)

1. Either inject the `IConfiguration` and use the same key-based approach like above. Or
2. Register an instance of the strongly-typed configuration object with the DI container, and inject that object directly into client classes.

Sample code below:

```
//In Startup.ConfigureServices()
var clientConfig = Configuration.GetSection("configuredClients")
    .Get<ClientConfiguration>();
services.AddSingleton(clientConfig);

//Controller
public class TestController : Controller
{
    IConfiguration _configStore;
    ClientConfiguration _clientConfiguration;

    public TestController(IConfiguration configuration, 
        ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration)
    {
        _configStore = configuration;
        _clientConfiguration = clientConfiguration;
    }

    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        //with IConfiguration
        var clientId1 = _configStore
            .GetValue<string>("configuredClients:clients:0:clientId");

        //with strongly typed ClientConfiguration
        var clientName1 = _clientConfiguration.Clients[0]?.ClientName;

        return new OkObjectResult("Configuration test");
    }
}
```

More examples [here](http://arghya.xyz/articles/practical-configuration-and-di-in-aspnet-core/).

Comment: For the scenario you presented the best solution would be to do `services.Configure<ClientConfiguration>(Configuration.GetSection("configuredClients"))` then instead of injecting `IConfiguration` into your controller inject `IOptions<ClientConfiguration>`.

Comment: Here, I showed injecting `IConfiguration` as one of the options, I've also shown injecting the `ClientConfiguration` directly. The "best" solution depends on multiple factors. Using `IOptions<>` is also an option, so is `IOptionsSnapshot` and others.

Answer (score 2):

You don't read the configuration manually generally in ASP.NET Core yourself, instead you create an object that matches your definition. You can read more on that in the official documentation [here](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html).

E.g.

```
public class MyOptions
{
    public string Option1 { get; set; }
    public int Option2 { get; set; }
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Setup options with DI
    services.AddOptions();
    services.Configure<MyOptions>(Configuration);
}
```

Then you just inject the options `IOptions<MyOptions>` where you need them.

Comment: The same does not work, even if the configuration object and the json object matched in the way you're suggesting, I am still getting null. Configuring the service and injecting IOptions later seems to retrieve the config values fine. The problem is when I am attempting to retrieve those values to use in Startup

Comment: I am not 100% sure what you mean, but would using DI container during Configure method help you? I think it's possible to use the container there, but cannot find how to do that.

Comment: This is a nice article on how to use strongly typed configuration sections : [How to use the IOptions pattern for configuration in ASP.NET Core RC2](http://andrewlock.net/how-to-use-the-ioptions-pattern-for-configuration-in-asp-net-core-rc2/)

Comment: Thanks for the help, but its not a solution to the problem I was having. After updating Configuration and ConfigurationExtensions packages to 1.1.0-preview1-final @Tom Makin's solution was perfect.

Comment: Sorry that I could not help, seems I have misunderstood your question partially :)

Comment: What if I actually need them in startup class?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get first "clientName"(expected "Client1"), just write:

```
Configuration.GetSection("configuredClients")["clients:0:clientName"];
```

**Update for comment**

Install .NET Core 1.0.1 and go with @TomMakin's way.

Comment: I want the full list of clients, obviously with it being configurable there is x number of clients that need to be used later in the configuration setup. So not really a viable solution.

Comment: Install .NET Core 1.0.1 and go with @TomMakin's way.