# Actually read AppSettings in ConfigureServices phase in ASP.NET Core

Tags: configuration, asp.net-core, app-config, startup, sections

I need to setup a few dependencies (services) in the `ConfigureServices` method in an ASP.NET Core 1.0 web application.

The issue is that based on the new JSON configuration I need to setup a service or another.

I can't seem to actually read the settings in the `ConfigureServices` phase of the app lifetime:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var section = Configuration.GetSection("MySettings"); // this does not actually hold the settings
    services.Configure<MySettingsClass>(section); // this is a setup instruction, I can't actually get a MySettingsClass instance with the settings
    // ...
    // set up services
    services.AddSingleton(typeof(ISomething), typeof(ConcreteSomething));
}
```

I would need to actually read that section and decide what to register for `ISomething` (maybe a different type than `ConcreteSomething`).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/40397648/5426333

Comment: @ademcaglin : Thanks! That was it. I voted for closing my own question as a duplicate of that one :)

Comment: The linked answer is to get values from the config file, not the appsettings.json file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Core Configuration Section in Startup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40397648/asp-net-core-configuration-section-in-startup)

Answer (score 77):

That is the way you can get the typed settings from `appSettings.json` right in `ConfigureServices` method:

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<MySettings>(Configuration.GetSection(nameof(MySettings)));
        services.AddSingleton(Configuration);

        // ...

        var settings = Configuration.GetSection(nameof(MySettings)).Get<MySettings>();
        int maxNumberOfSomething = settings.MaxNumberOfSomething;

        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 18):

Starting from ASP.NET Core 2.0 we do configuration setup in `Program` class when building `WebHost` instance. Example of such setup:

```cs
return new WebHostBuilder()
    .UseKestrel()
    .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((builderContext, config) =>
    {
        IHostingEnvironment env = builderContext.HostingEnvironment;

        config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
    })
```

Among others, this allows using configuration directly in `Startup` class, getting an instance of `IConfiguration` via constructor injection (thank you, built-in DI container):

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    ...
}
```

Comment: yeah! worked for me. finally i can get my stuff from json entries to prepare my services :\

Comment: How does this work when an ASP.NET Core 2.1 application is hosted under IIS? The `WebHostBuilder` won't be used, so what is in that `IConfiguration configuration` that's passed into `Startup`'s constructor?

Answer (score 5):

You can access appsettings.json values by `Configuration["ConfigSection:ConfigValue"])`

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(o => 
            o.UseSqlServer(Configuration["AppSettings:SqlConn"]));
    }
}
```

appsettings.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AppSettings": {
    "SqlConn": "Data Source=MyServer\\MyInstance;Initial Catalog=MyDb;User ID=sa;Password=password;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False;"
  }
}
```

Comment: No, the object Configuration came as null

Answer (score 1):

The **appsettings.json** file :

```
  "MyApp": {
    "Jwt": {
      "JwtSecretConfigKey": "jwtSecretConfigKey",
      "Issuer": "appIssuer",
      "Audience": "appAudience",
      "ExpireMinutes": 60
    }
  }
```

add a class to bind **Jwt section** of "MyApp" ...

```
   public class JwtConfig
    {
        public string JwtSecretConfigKey { get; set; }
        public string Issuer { get; set; }
        public string Audience { get; set; }
        public int ExpireMinutes { get; set; }
    }
```

In **ConfigureServices** method :

```
//reading config from appsettings.json
var jwtConfig = Configuration.GetSection("MyApp:Jwt").Get<JwtConfig>();

//using config data ....
services.AddJwt(new AddJwtOptions(jwtConfig.JwtSecretConfigKey, jwtConfig.Issuer, jwtConfig.Audience, jwtConfig.ExpireMinutes));
```

The code below is the same as above. it works as well...

```
var jwtConfig = Configuration.GetSection("MyApp").GetSection("Jwt").Get<JwtConfig>();
```

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 1):

Try next:

```
var settings = new MySettings();
Configuration.GetSection(nameof(MySettings)).Bind(settings);
```

Answer (score 1):

This took me a horrifically long time but I got there in the end using `IConfiguration.Bind()`.

I particularly wanted a flat configuration file rather than having to define a section.

Example `appsettings.json`:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "MyApiBaseUrl": "https://api.example.com",
  "MyApiKey": "example-api-key",
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

We need a helper class to bind to `CustomApplicationConfiguration`:

```
public class CustomApplicationConfiguration
{
    public string MyApiBaseUrl { get; set; }
    public string MyApiKey { get; set; }
}
```

Then define and bind inside `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var settings = new ApplicationConfiguration();
    Configuration.Bind(settings);

    Console.WriteLine(settings.MyApiBaseUrl); // https://api.example.com
    Console.WriteLine(settings.MyApiKey); // example-api-key
```